# How to configure Botium core to test a directline3 chatbot hosted in Web. Could someone please guide me in here?

Tags: botium-box

I want to automate a voice based chatbot hosted in web. Could some please help me in where to start with? There is not much documentation on how to configure Botium binding and start executing. Could someone please help me here

Answer (score 0):

You can do voice-based testing with the Botium Directline3 connector. It will connect directly over the Directline interface. The Botium Webdriver connector doesn't support voice-based testing for now.

When testing a chatbot, it is general a bad idea to start testing on something "hosted in web" - sure, this should be done somehow, but starting on an API level (like Directline) brings quicker and more siginificant results. Read on here: https://floriantreml.medium.com/upskilling-test-engineers-for-chatbot-projects-44c96e4f26a0

Comment: Does the Directine3 connector sopport voice based testing?

Comment: yes it supports sending and receiving audio files